# Basic authentication logout on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have run into a little problem. I am connecting to a webservice that use Basic authentication and now I want the user to either: be able to log out, or that each time the request is made a new authentication is made. Right now the authentication seems to be cached. How do I do this?

I tried to append `#` at the end, but that did not seem to do the trick. The URL has the following format:

`www.example.org/mywebservice/data`

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"www.example.org/mywebservice/data"];
NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection* newConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.myConnection = newConnection;

[request release];
[newConnection release];
```

Comment: can we see how you are handling the connection to the web service? Are you using NSUrlConnection?

Comment: Yes I am using NSURLConnection

Comment: did you look at this: http://www.springenwerk.com/2008/11/i-am-currently-building-iphone.html

Comment: @Dude u mean your data coming through cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. I changed `NSURLCredentialPersistenceSession` to `NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone`.

```
    NSURLCredential *cred = [[[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:user.username password:user.password
                                                       persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to clear the cache of the previous requests and every time want to do new request at login. So for that just put below code before doing request for login

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies]) 
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

May help you

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I have to say this solved a problem I was having with authentication token caching in a legacy app that was using an older AFNetworking library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the Authentication header in your `NSURLRequest`?

```
[urlRequest setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```